# python addition asking from the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

The math statement is "add x1 and x2"

The output of python is:
Enter the statement or "E" to exit the program:

Then user inputs:
add 35 and 5

The output is:
Answer: add 35 and 5 = 40

How to use python to code this output?
Enter the statement or "E" to exit the program: add 35 and 5
Answer: add 35 and 5 = 40

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is `print:` - it isn't python?

Comment: Welcome to SO, check out [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You'ĺl need to use the .split() to separate the user inputs contained in the string.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
user_input=input("enter the statement:")
x1=int(user_input.split()[0])
x2=int(user_input.split()[1])
print("Answer: Add {} and {} = {}".format(x1,x2,x1+x2))
```

But you should check that the user used "add" and "and" using if, to make sure the user statement was as you desired.

Answer (score -1):

```
action = input("Enter the statement [add] or E to exit the program: ")
if action == "add":
    x1 = int(input("enter the first number: "))
    x2 = int(input("enter the second number: "))
    print("Answer: Add {} and {} = {}". format(x1,x2,x1+x2))
elif action == "E" or action == "e":
    # exit action 
    exit("Goodbye")
else:
    # unexpected action
    exit("Error: invaild action {}".format(action))
```